# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login()

Tags: laravel, twilio-api

I have tried everything in the answer with the similar issue but I am still stuck in this error help me. I know where it came from but I don't know how to solve this one.

```
<?php




use RegistersUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/verify';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */

protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        'mobile' => ['required', 'min:10'],
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param array $request
 * @return string
 * @throws \Twilio\Exceptions\ConfigurationException
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    /* Get credentials from .env */
    $token = getenv("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");
    $twilio_sid = getenv("TWILIO_SID");
    $twilio_verify_sid = getenv("TWILIO_VERIFY_SID");
    $twilio = new Client($twilio_sid, $token);
    $twilio->verify->v2->services($twilio_verify_sid)
        ->verifications
        ->create('+977'.$data['mobile'], "sms");
    User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'mobile' => $data['mobile'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('verify')->with('mobile', $data->mobile);

}
protected function verify(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->validate([
        'otp' => ['required', 'numeric'],
        'mobile' => ['required', 'string'],
    ]);
    /* Get credentials from .env */
    $token = getenv("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");
    $twilio_sid = getenv("TWILIO_SID");
    $twilio_verify_sid = getenv("TWILIO_VERIFY_SID");
    $twilio = new Client($twilio_sid, $token);
    $verification = $twilio->verify->v2->services($twilio_verify_sid)
        ->verificationChecks
        ->create($data['otp'], array('to' => $data['mobile']));
    if ($verification->valid) {
        $user = tap(User::where('mobile', $data['mobile']))->update(['isVerified' => true]);
        /* Authenticate user */
        Auth::login($user->first());
        return redirect()->route('dashboard')->with(['message' => 'Phone number verified']);
    }
    return back()->with(['mobile' => $data['mobile'], 'error' => 'Invalid verification code entered!']);
}
```

}

and this is my route:

```
    <?php


Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/verify', function () {
    return view('backend.verify');
})->name('verify');

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth.register');
})->name('register');

Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::post('/verify', 'RegisterController@verify')->name('verify');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::resource('user', 'UserController', ['except' => ['show']]);
    Route::get('profile', ['as' => 'profile.edit', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@edit']);
    Route::put('profile', ['as' => 'profile.update', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@update']);
    Route::put('profile/password', ['as' => 'profile.password', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@password']);

});
```

I can add code if necessary thank you. I think the problem is in create function which redirect to route verify and the error is:
[image]

Comment: Please check your UserController class definition.  in sample bellow code is missing.  
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class UserController extends Controller
{

Comment: @QamarRafhan It's far more likely those lines of code were omitted from the question as they aren't really relevant to the error :)

Answer (score 3):

Create method must return $user object. You cannot redirect to any route from the create method of your RegisterController. There are ways you can handle this.

Overwrite your default registration route in your web.php like this.

```
Route::post('/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@created')->name('register');
```

and then in your registration controller change params from type array to Illuminate\Http\Request like this.

```
protected function created(Request $data)
{
/* Get credentials from .env */
$token = getenv("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");
$twilio_sid = getenv("TWILIO_SID");
$twilio_verify_sid = getenv("TWILIO_VERIFY_SID");
$twilio = new Client($twilio_sid, $token);
$twilio->verify->v2->services($twilio_verify_sid)
->verifications
->create('+977'.$data->mobile, "sms");
User::create([
  'name' => $data->name,
  'mobile' => $data->mobile,
  'email' => $data->email,
  'password' => Hash::make($data->password),
]);

return redirect()->route('verify')->with('mobile', $data->mobile);

}
```

Hope this will solve your issues. :)

Comment: actually, I overwrite create method which does not return `User` but I want to redirect route to `verify()` function which create otp and login user. How do I do it any idea?

Comment: yes I am getting the same error. I try to return `User` but I don't want that because it take me to dashboard. As of LoginController `protected $redirectTo = '/verify';` I have this which redirect to `verify`.

Comment: Try this solution

Comment: yes I tried this one also but did not work. It take me back to dashboard, but I want to go to view file of `verify()` function.

Comment: I think my user has not been created yet so, it will throw error of trying to get property. and if I place @ it will ignore every thing. I think I am hopeless here still have not solve this error

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps try instead of:

`$user = tap(User::where('mobile', $data['mobile']))->update(['isVerified' => true]);`

just

`$user = User::where('mobile', $data['mobile'])->get()->first()->update(['isVerified' => true]);`

and then
`Auth::login($user);`

I assume `User` model extends `Authenticatable`

Comment: In your code, `$user` would be a Boolean (true or false). `->update()` doesn't return the `User` instance, and `Auth::login(true/false)` is also invalid. `$user = User::where('mobile', $data['mobile'])->first();`, followed by `$user->update(['isVerified' => true]);` then `Auth::login($user);` should work.

Comment: @TimLewis You are right. So it should be enough to just do:
`Auth::login($user->get()->first()`

Here's similar example in the documentation"
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-tap

Comment: Not quite; see my full comment above; there's 3 distinct lines. Sidenote, don't bother with `... ->get()->first()`; `->first()` calls `->get()` internally, so it's redundant to use it like that.

Comment: @TimLewis did not work. Same error occur. Otp is create, I got text message but same error occurs. thank you for your comment